# Can user #1 (the initial user) be deleted without ill effect?

Tags: admin, privileges

When you create a new Wordpress site, the first user created is user #1 and given the Administrator role.  Is there anything special about user #1 that would make it unwise to delete it?  (Assuming that there were other users with Administrator role.)

Comment: Nope. In fact, some plugins that attempt to secure WP through obscurity actually use this as a method to make your DB not match the "standard" layout.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that’s safe. I have done that. The core does not rely on the existence of such a user.

There might be some broken plugins whose authors think user 1 is always there *and* an admin, they will not work properly. On the other hand, this is a very simple test for a plugin: If it doesn’t work after you have deleted user 1, it is probably very insecure, and you need an alternative anyway.

Comment: I've done it too with no problems. Worth noting that in multisite a super admin is required, and before being able to delete *original* super admin after created a second one, the super admin capabilitites should be revoked and the network admin email must be different from the one set as user email for original admin.